# Qgis Least Cost Path with certain threshold

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, grass-gis, cost-path

I have DEM data on which I have performed Slope Analysis and extracted contours from it as well. After slope analysis the contours with slope greater than 450 have been transformed into polygons (considered as obstacles). Now I would like to create two points on this map and want to find a path that will avoid these obstacles (contours having slope value greater than 450).

How can I create two points?
How can I find the path drawing between these two points, that will avoid the obstacles?

I am working in QGIS.